# How to emulate mousedown or click event on a React component in WhatsApp Web from browser console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, whatsapp

[WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/) seems to run on React.

How to dispatch a mouse click or mousedown event on a contact on the left to open dialog - from browser JS console?

Contact component is rendered as hierarchy of div and span elements, and mousedown event capture seems to be happening immediately under the top div#app element.

Some of my attempts:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('div._2wP_Y')[3];
// try 1
el.dispatchEvent(
  new Event("mousedown", {bubbles: true})
); // also tried setting other props incl. target, currentTarget

// try 2
el.click();
```

However nothing happens.

Does the reason of this hide in React itself or is it more probable that WA made some sort of protection against such user actions?

Comment: Did you find any solution @Serge ?

Comment: @Azat, no solution so far.  Only found that with a simple react component all of the above code works. So it must be WhatsApp that implemented additional protection against such manipulations. Perhaps, they are checking the [isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) property of mouse events, which I don't know how to forge.